# Replacing any NULL fields with a string

Tags: sql, replace, null

I'm new to SQL and this problem has stumped me. I am supposed to write an SQL statement that lists all the data in a table, but if a column might contain NULL values (in this case only one field is NULL), the phrase "-NONE-" must print in that column for that row. The lab hints that I must use one or more single-row functions to accomplish this.

We are using Oracle SQL Developer to test scripts. I am trying to use the REPLACE function but I keep getting errors. I've tried using NVAL, REPLACE, and other similar functions but I am clearly getting the syntax wrong. For example:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(manager_id, NULL, '-NONE-')
FROM departments;
```

^Always returns an error: missing FROM statement where expected

Answer (score 4):

The function you want is `coalesce()`.  This is the ANSI standard function.

Assuming your variable is a character string:

```
SELECT d.*, COALESCE(manager_id, '-NONE-')
FROM departments d;
```

If it is not a string, then convert it first:

```
SELECT d.*, COALESCE(cast(manager_id as varchar(255)), '-NONE-')
FROM departments d;
```

Comment: much better than my answer

Comment: So, I tried this both ways and I get the same "FROM keyword not found where expected". Any idea why? The following code returns the right row with the string inserted:  
SELECT COALESCE(cast(manager_id AS varchar(225)), '-NONE-') 
FROM departments;  
But when I include the '*' selector I get that error message. (Sorry about the shitty formatting -- new to this site =/)

Comment: @user3281385 . . . Some databases let you use `*` and add additional columns.  Others require that you use a table alias plus a `*`.  The above should work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this might help you:

```
select 
    *, 
    (case when manager_id is null then '-none-' else manager_id end) as manager_id_2
from 
    departments
```